# Write as sum: $2x_{1}x_{2}+3x_{2}x_{3}^{2}+4x_{3}x_{4}^{3}+5x_{4}x_{5}^{4}+6x_{5}x_{6}^{5}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, arithmetic

> Write as sum:
>   $2x_{1}x_{2}+3x_{2}x_{3}^{2}+4x_{3}x_{4}^{3}+5x_{4}x_{5}^{4}+6x_{5}x_{6}^{5}$

I wrote like this but not sure if correct. I made tests and it seems correct but I ask just to be very sure:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{5}(i+1)x_{i}x_{i+1}^{i}$$

Comment: It looks good except you have a typo: the last term in the summand should be $x_{i+1}^i$ rather than $x_i^i + 1$...

Comment: The base should be x_(i+1) and exponent is i. And why have you added a 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{5}(i+1)x_{i}x_{i+1}^{i}.
$$

Comment: beat me to the answer :)

Comment: oh yeah I typed correct on paper but wrong here thank you! :)